# CSS Media Queries -> Link vs @media

Tags: html, css, media-queries

It's my understanding that defining media queries in the HTML file within the `<link>` tag rather than by using `@media only...` in external CSS files allows you to have a large number of specific files modularized and specific to the device is being targeted, and only the files you need will be retrieved by the browser

Is this correct?

Comment: See also [*Difference Between HTML LINK Media and CSS Media Queries*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25711297/difference-between-html-link-media-and-css-media-queries).