# The difference between HTML media queries and CSS media queries

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I know that media queries can be declared within either HTML or CSS:

**HTML LINK:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="foo.css" media="(max-width: 1024px)">
```

**CSS:**

```css
@media all and (max-width: 1024px) {
    ...
}
```

I have read the documentation and I think I understand most of the differences between the two methods. However, I'm still left with the following questions:

1. For HTML linked resources with media queries, will browsers download the linked resource *only* when the media query's conditions are met?

2. Lets say if a CSS file also has media queries for smaller widths other than 1024px, something like this:

   ```css
   body {
       padding: 10px;
   }     
   @media all and (max-width: 900px) {
       body {
           padding: 5px;
       }     
    }    
   @media all and (max-width: 800px) {
       body {
           padding: 0px;
       }     
   }
   ```

   If the above file is added using an HTML link like this:

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" htef="foo.css" media="(max-width: 1024px)">
   ```

   Would this be treated as a nested media query? In other words, will the browser interpret it like this?

   ```css
   @media all and (max-width: 1024px) {
       body {
           padding: 10px;
       } 

       @media all and (max-width: 900px) {
           body {
               padding: 5px;
           }   
       }

       @media all and (max-width: 800px) {
           body {
               padding: 0px;
           }   
       }
   }
   ```

   I may have further media queries inside a CSS file that is linked with a media query condition that I would want to apply as well.

Comment: I'm just going to throw an idea out there as I don't know for sure. When it comes to inclusion I believe the media queries are only a selector to the contained css, not a boolean for execution. I'd imagine that the browser will download and compile all resources regardless of media query and simply apply the rules where it's appropriate.

Comment: So I suppose in the end, the link tag media attribute's only utility is in helping modularize your responsive CSS code...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Regarding the stylesheet download, here is what the current [spec draft](http://drafts.csswg.org/mediaqueries/#media) says:

> User agents should re-evaluate media queries in response to changes in the user environment, for example if the device is tiled from landscape to portrait orientation, and change the behavior of any constructs dependent on those media queries accordingly.

This means you can’t just evaluate each media-query and then download the appropriate stylesheets because the environment can change, causing the re-evaluation of these media-queries. I think it could be optimized, but for now [all browsers](https://scottjehl.github.io/CSS-Download-Tests/) download all stylesheets, regardless of media-queries.

For your second question, specs don’t mention any difference between HTML- and CSS-declared media-queries. Nested media-queries are allowed since CSS3, and putting `@media`-rules in a stylesheet which is already tagged with `media="…"` should be the same as a pure CSS nested media-query.

Answer (score 16):

Here is what W3C has to [say about this](https://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/document-metadata.html#attr-link-media):

> The media attribute says which media the resource applies to. The
> value must be a valid media query.
>
> [...]
>
> However, if the link is an external resource link, then the media
> attribute is prescriptive. The user agent must apply the external
> resource when the media attribute's value matches the environment and
> the other relevant conditions apply, and must not apply it otherwise.
>
> **Note:** The external resource might have further restrictions defined within
> that limit its applicability. For example, a CSS style sheet might
> have some @media blocks. This specification does not override such
> further restrictions or requirements.

I tested the behavior in Chrome using the following markup:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ge-960.css" media="screen and (min-width: 960px)">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lt-960.css" media="screen and (max-width: 959px)">
```

- Chrome downloaded all CSS files regardless of screen resolution. However, it applied the rules from matching stylesheet(s) only
- And it honored all matching `@media` rules within the stylesheet declared with a media attribute

Answer (score 9):

> For HTML linked resources with media queries, **will browsers download the linked resource *only* when the media query's conditions are met**?

This (the emphasized portion) is a very common misconception about stylesheets loaded via media queries in `<link>` elements.

All files will be loaded regardless of the media queries being applied to `<link>` elements. A file is not loaded only when a media query is met, because there is no guarantee that the browser won't meet it (or even stop meeting it) when some of its properties change while viewing the same page.

For instance if you rotate a mobile device from portrait to landscape, it would stop matching `(orientation: portrait)` and start matching `(orientation: landscape)`. It needs to make sure the styles in the latter are ready to apply as it switches to that format, so the styles have to be loaded beforehand.

The [HTML5 spec for the `<link>` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-link-element) does not make any mention of how the `media` attribute should determine whether or not a resource should be loaded. The [Media Queries spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries) doesn't define how style sheets should be loaded with respect to media queries, however it does state this in a note:

> User agents are expected, but not required, to re-evaluate and re-layout the page in response to changes in the user environment, for example if the device is tilted from landscape to portrait mode.

Comment: Gotcha.  Makes sense.  So, in essence, they are equal, right?

Comment: @user1167442: Yes - you do have to send an extra HTTP request for each separate stylesheet, but they're otherwise equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

With HTML media queries, the CSS files are downloaded whether or not the media query is satisfied or not. But the prasing of unwanted CSS is kind of deferred and this advances your initial render. In a way, you can think of making it, non-render blocking. But with CSS media queries, they are completely parsed and processed whether or not the query is satisfied.

Comment: Thank you for this information! This is also mentioned in [this doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Performance/CSS#optimizing_for_render_blocking). I think this optimization can be quite useful when one has 10 different stylesheets for different screens.

Answer (score 0):

> For HTML linked resources with media queries, will browsers download the linked resource *only* when the media query's conditions are met?

No, linked resources will be loaded regardless of any media attribute values.

If your goal is to only load the media needed for a given device, you can use @import followed by media queries. @import does not load the external CSS if the media query is not supported or does not apply to the browser. This means, however, that @import files with conditional queries based on screen orientation either imports the file when the screen orientation changes, or never loads the CSS at all even when the orientation switches.