# CSS: media query CSS not working 50% of the time (Chrome)

Tags: html, css

I have a site where I am using a media query link element to apply some overriding CSS when the width of the browser goes below a certain pixel width.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media='screen and (max-width: 960px)' href='css/mainNarrow.css' />
```

The issue is, 50% of the time, the second stylesheet does not seem to kick in when the width of the browser is changed. I am using Chrome 58.0.3029.96 (64-bit). Inspecting the elements, the second stylesheet does not seem to even be present, so I do not believe it is a precedence issue.

Here is the site, so that you can refresh and resize to experiment yourself. Half the time I refresh, the resize behavior is different. You can tell when the second stylesheet kicks in, by the top menu being replaced by a hamburger menu button:

http://www.multipleorganics.com

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: You can try ...<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

Comment: If you check the source of the site, you will see it is already there. doesn't seem to have an effect.

Comment: Do you know how it behaves in any other browsers?

Comment: Could it be possible that both links need the media attribute?

Comment: you can write media query like @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
    #top-table{
        background-color: green;
    }
}

Comment: What @Niles Tanner points is correct. I just test it and worked.

Comment: @dqhendricks It should probably just be `media='screen'`.

Comment: @NilesTanner I just tried `media='screen'`, same result. Second stylesheet did not kick in.

Comment: @NilesTanner or Joan, do you know why the first stylesheet wouldn't load without a `media` attribute? It should load that one before even looking at the second `<link>`, right?

Comment: There is no guarantee as to the order of the loading. Using a media attribute on both links was a shot in the dark. In my testing it seems that this is a async issue that resolves it's self when the page fully loads

Comment: @NilesTanner the page is fully loaded for me, and still not working. This is not the same issue you are describing.

Comment: @dqhendricks Your right the page sometimes 'locks' to the media query that pertains to it when it is fully loaded.

Comment: @dqhendricks Have you tried removing the first `link` and only having it load the narrow one? Does it load correctly every time that way?

Comment: @freginold Can't reproduce in IE

Comment: @dqhendricks This link might help with making media queries for both links http://stackoverflow.com/a/25713528/6739517 Also it looks like this might be your answer.

Comment: @NilesTanner This is not what I want. I do not want the first one to only be used when above a certain width. I want it to be used always, but certain styles overwritten by the second stylesheet when below a certain width.

Answer (score 3):

You should probably just add that css as a secondary style sheet and remove that media attribute. Within your style you wrap your code in the media query such as:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 960px) { /*960*/
  // Put your CSS code here...
}
```

Comment: But do I have to? I'd rather these be separate files. Why doesn't the other method work? From what I understand, it is supposed to be functionally the same.

Comment: @Adrianopolis This method should work the same way as OP's method in theory.

Comment: This is generally the better approach because it decreases the number of HTTP requests that need to be made for the page to load, which will result in an overall quicker load time.

Comment: @ScottMarcus But functionally it should work the same as OP's method, correct?

Comment: @freginold Well, because of load times and potential HTTP resource queuing, the second file may not get loaded in time to respond to the query it's designed to support.

Comment: @ScottMarcus It doesn't seem to matter how long you wait before resizing. It's not a latency issue I am trying to solve. It's mechanical.

Comment: This is not a big app so I wouldn't worry horribly about the extra request for the css file. If you prefer, you can take my instruction with the media query css and append it to your main css file. End of story. Then you eliminate the second stylesheet link.

Comment: Just a note I have never had issues using media query in the stylesheet itself. Always consistent and cross browser compatible. But just for a sanity check have you tried changing max-width to max-device-width?  I doubt that will solve your issue but worth a test.

Comment: @Adrianopolis yeah I did try that. did not seem to have an effect. I will try a single stylesheet and see if that works.