# Which media query method is more efficient?

Tags: css, media-queries

I have a website and I created a mobile theme for it. Basically, my CSS file is currently split into three sections: 1) General styles, 2) Desktop/laptop-specific styles, and 3) Mobile-specific styles.

All of the rules are in a single CSS file, but the different blocks are applied using media queries, like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width:1149px) {
     /*Rules here*/
}
```

This works fine but it means that the CSS file is really larger than it needs to be. Would it be more efficient to use an HTML-level media query instead, like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width:1149px)" href="style.css"/>
```

My assumption is that the browser will only load the relevant CSS file, therefore saving data and speeding the loading process. But at the same time, it would create another network request for another file, which could slow performance.

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20876052/924299) from [BoltClock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock), "[a]ll files will be loaded regardless of the media queries being applied to <link> elements."

Comment: You might find these articles interesting: [Debunking Responsive CSS Performance Myths](https://www.igvita.com/2012/06/14/debunking-responsive-css-performance-myths/) and [Conditional loading of resources with mediaqueries](https://christianheilmann.com/2012/12/19/conditional-loading-of-resources-with-mediaqueries/).

Comment: So the answer is: one file is more efficient than two or more, because of the overhead involved in downloading each file.