# Difference between style tag's media attribute and media at rule

Tags: css, media-queries

What is the difference between specifying rules in style tags that have a [media attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_style_media.asp) and under a [@media](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) rule?

This:

```
<style media="print">
    body { color: green; }
</style>
```

and this:

```
<style>
    @media only print {
        body { color: green; }
    }
</style>
```

have the same effect on my computer: the text is black but if I press [Ctrl]+[p], then Chrome shows the print preview with green letters.

So is there an advantage to any of these, is one of the approaches deprecated, or is the browser-support different? Which one should I use?

Comment: checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20875888/css-media-queries-link-vs-media and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25711297/difference-between-html-link-media-and-css-media-queries

Comment: Both things do the same. However the `style` tags are not encouraged. Better use external CSS files by using `link`.